# Parse content within angular directive template before rendering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-directive

Since there is no `ng-url` directive to use with an `@import` statement the way `ng-src` works, I am trying to create a directive for this purpose, the code is like this

```
.directive('importCss',

    function()
    {

        return {

            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            scope: { loadCss : '=' },
            template:'<style>' +
                     '    @import url("{{loadCss}}")' +
                     '</style>',

        };
    }
);
```

The idea basically is to create HTML like this:

```
<style>
   @import url("http://url_to_css_in_parameter")
</style>
```

Probably this is something very basic, but what is happening is that in my controller I have some `init` code that runs before asigning values to the scope var assigned to the `loadCss` parameter. The value is initialized to '' at the start of the controller code.  The problem is that a request is made to the server requesting "http://serverAddr/{{loadCss}}"  before it does the actual correct request with the values applied to the template.

Here is the callstack for the wrong request (screenshot):

[image: Seems like the request ends in jQuery (jqLite?)]

Any idea while the template is being rendered before compiling and how to solve it?  Thanks very much.

Comment: "I have some init code that runs before asigning values to the scope var assigned to the loadCss parameter." -- if this init code includes some async calls, then it will return the loadCss without getting the correct value first.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Hieu, it actually doesn't, neither it uses any promises at all, however it acts like when rendering the template if first would render the uncompiled version and that would be causing the call, then after compilation it works by generating the correct request.  (???)

Comment: Is it possible to $compile the template earlier in the directive creation process, so that when it renders in the browser it does it with the right values added?